# How to notify a parent thread of job completion in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-multithreading

I would like to use the following code to find a specific number of permutations in a list.

```
def permutations(ls, prefix, result):
    if ls:
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            permutations([*ls[0:i], *ls[i + 1:]], [*prefix, ls[i]], result)
    else:
        result.append(prefix)

    return result
```

My issue is that I cannot simply include another parameter to count the number of permutations found. I can't do that because each recursive call to `permutations()` "splits" into a new "version" (it's like a fork in the road with the old counter and each branch counts its own number of permutations found, not communicating with the others). In other words, this won't work:

```
def permutations(ls, prefix, result, count, limit):
    if count > limit:
        return 

    if ls:
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            permutations([*ls[0:i], *ls[i + 1:]], [*prefix, ls[i]], result)
    else:
        count += 1
        result.append(prefix)

    return result
```

So what I would like to do instead of including a `count` parameter in the function signature, is to notify some other part of my program every time a new permutation is found, and keep track of the count that way. This may be a good use of threading, but I would like to do it without parallelization if possible (or at least the simplest parallelized solution possible).

I realize that I would have to spawn a new thread at each call to `permutations([*ls[0:i], *ls[i + 1:]], [*prefix, ls[i]], result)` in the for loop.

I'm hoping that someone would be so kind as to point me in the right direction or let me know if there is a better way to do this in Python.

Comment: *"This may be a good use of threading"* - huh? If you are not currently using threads, then what is the question about?

Comment: umm, let's see ... how can I stop early to find a specific number `n` permutations for a sequence of length `m` without finding all possible `m!` permutations? It seems like I would _have_ to use threading. If so, how? If not... how?

Comment: When you don't have multi-threading right now, you can safely update a global (or higher-scope) counter variable and make the iteration/recursion depend on that value.

Comment: Thanks! Funny enough, I forgot about those. I don't use global variables often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using threading, then I recommend not using threading and also not *thinking* in terms of using threading.

The reason is that the more simply and directly you are able to tackle a problem, the easier it is to think about.

As a second tip, any time you find yourself iterating through permutations, you probably should find a better approach.  The reason is that the number of permutations of length `n` grows as `n!`, and depending on what you are doing/your patience, computers top out somewhere between `n=10` and `n=15`.  So finding ways to count without actually iterating becomes essential.  How do do that, of course, depends on your problem.

But back to the problem as stated.  I would personally solve this type of problem in Python using [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generators).  That is, you have code that can produce the next element of the list in a generator, and then elsewhere you can have code that processes it.  This allows you to start processing your list right away, and not keep it all in memory.

In a language without generators, I would tackle this with closures.  That is you pass in a function (or object) that you call for each value, which does whatever it wants to do.  That again allows you to separate the iteration logic from the logic of what you want to do with each iteration.

If you're working with some other form of cooperative multi-tasking, use that instead.  So, for example, in JavaScript you would have to figure out how to coordinate using Promises.  (Luckily the async/await syntax lets you do that and make it look almost like a generator approach.  Note that you may wind up with large parts of the data set in memory at once.  How to avoid that is a topic in and of itself.)  For another example, in Go you should use channels and goroutines.

I would only go to global variables as a last resort.  And if you do, remember that you need enough memory to keep the entire data set that you iterated over in memory at once.  This may be a lot of memory!

I prefer all of these over the usual multi-threading approach.